# Как определить был ли вызван SetEvent?

Tags: c++, c, winapi, синхронизация

Мне необходимо сделать общение 2х разных программ через `Pipe`, клиент которой является инъекционной библиотекой для другого процесса. Далее, мне нужно сделать так, что бы поток был остановлен и клиент отключился, при завершении процесса, или же при поступлении сообщения о завершении работы сервера, или просто пропала связь с сервером.

Для синхронизации использую `CreateEvent`, `OpenEvent` и `SetEvent`.

И не могу понять, как используя `WaitForSingleObject` в цикле крутить обработку сообщений от сервера, и при этом не ждать вечно установки события через `SetEvent`.

```
/* Чего здесь ждать? */
while (?? != WaitForSingleObject(h_event, 0)) {
    ...
}
```

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include "kokin_client.h"

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif // __cplusplus

#define KOKIN_EVENT_NAME                TEXT("kokin_process_detach")
#define KOKIN_PIPE_SERVER_NAME          "kokin://shinra/renderer"

static HANDLE h_thread_handle           = INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE;
static HANDLE h_thread_process_ended    = INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE;
static struct kokin_client *p_client    = KOKIN_CLIENT_INVALID;

DWORD CALLBACK kokin_start(LPVOID p_user_data) {
    int i_result;
    HANDLE h_event;

    p_client = kokin_client_new();

    if (KOKIN_CLIENT_INVALID == p_client) {
        return 1;
    }
    
    i_result = kokin_client_connect(p_client, KOKIN_PIPE_SERVER_NAME);

    if (0 != i_result) {
        return 2;
    }

    h_event = OpenEvent(SYNCHRONIZE, TRUE, KOKIN_EVENT_NAME);

    if (NULL == h_event) {
        return 3;
    }

    /* Чего здесь ждать? */
    while(?? != WaitForSingleObject(h_event, 0)) {
        kokin_client_process(p_client);
    }
}

/* https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/windows/win32/dlls/dllmain */

BOOL WINAPI DllMain(
    HINSTANCE hinstDLL,     /* handle to DLL module         */
    DWORD fdwReason,        /* reason for calling function  */
    LPVOID lpReserved)      /* reserved                     */
{
    /* Perform actions based on the reason for calling.     */
    switch (fdwReason)
    {
    case DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH: {
        /* Initialize once for each new process.            */
        /* Return FALSE to fail DLL load.                   */

        /* Double injection? Just fail to load and exit...  */
        if (INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE != h_thread_handle) {
            return FALSE;
        }

        h_thread_process_ended = CreateEvent(NULL, TRUE, FALSE, KOKIN_EVENT_NAME);
        h_thread_handle = CreateThread(NULL, 0, kokin_start, NULL, NULL, NULL);
    }   break;

    case DLL_THREAD_ATTACH:
        /* Do thread-specific initialization.               */
        break;

    case DLL_THREAD_DETACH:
        /* Do thread-specific cleanup.                      */
        break;

    case DLL_PROCESS_DETACH: {
        /* Perform any necessary cleanup.                   */

        (void) SetEvent(h_thread_process_ended);

        (void) WaitForSingleObject(h_thread_handle, INFINITE);

        (void) CloseHandle(h_thread_handle);
        (void) CloseHandle(h_thread_process_ended);
        kokin_client_destroy(&p_client);
    } break;
    }
    return TRUE;  /* Successful DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH.         */
}

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif // __cplusplus
```

P.S. Пожалуйста не предлагайте `c++`'ные потоки или что-то еще, только WinAPI.

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/synchapi/nf-synchapi-waitforsingleobject читали? Там в Return values расписано, чего от этой функции можно ждать и что это означает.

Comment: Хотя к сути вопроса это и не относится, но DllMain используется неверно. Все действия по инициализации библиотеки следует делать внутри специальной функции инициализации, которую клиент библиотеки должен вызывать явно, а не в DllMain.

Answer (score 1):

Если написать так:

```c
while (WAIT_OBJECT_0 != WaitForSingleObject(h_event, 0)) {
    kokin_client_process(p_client);
}
```

то цикл будет работать пока не будет вызван `SetEvent`

Так:

```c
DWORD dwMilliseconds = 1000;
if (WAIT_OBJECT_0 == WaitForSingleObject(h_event, dwMilliseconds )) 
{
    kokin_client_process(p_client);
}
```

программа будет ожидать вызова `SetEvent` в течении `dwMilliseconds`

Если таймаут не устраивает, то можно использовать `WaitForMultipleObjects`

```
HANDLE lpHandles[2];
lpHandles[0] = h_event;
lpHandles[1] = stop_event; 
DWORD  dwMilliseconds = INFINITE;

while(true)
{
     DWORD result = WaitForMultipleObjects(2, lpHandles, FALSE, dwMilliseconds );
     switch(result)
     {
        case WAIT_OBJECT_0:
        {
           kokin_client_process(p_client);
           break;
         }
         case WAIT_OBJECT_0 + 1:
         {
           break;
         }
         default:
            continue;
      }

}
```